# Issue in publishing custom events to socket.io channels in feathersjs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I am trying to publish data to a frontend angular application using socket.io in feathersjs. I have created a channel as follow and created mockData stream.

```
function mockData(app) {
    app.emit('testEvent', { test: 'Something happened'});
};
setInterval(mockData.bind(null, app), 1000);
app.publish('testEvent', (data) => { 
  console.log('test');
  return app.channel('testStream1');}
)
```

And when client is connected, I have added the client to testStream1 channel as follows.

```
 app.on('connection', connection => {
    // On a new real-time connection, add it to the anonymous channel
    app.channel('testStream1');
    app.channel('anonymous').join(connection);
    app.channel('testStream1').join(connection);
  });
```

Here nothing in `app.publish` callback executes, but if I try to directly emit from socketio object then I can receive values in client.

```
function mockData(app) {
  app.emit('testEvent', { test: 'Something happened'});
  app.io.emit('testStream1', { text: 'A client connected!' }); // Adding this line, I am able to get values from socketio client
};
```

Seems that `app.publish([event,] fn)` doesn't register the publishing function for custom event `testEvent`. How to get the data using `app.publish` ?

Answer (score 3):

It might be neat feature in the future but currently, publishers and channels are only intended for [service events](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html), not global events. Although the `app` object is an event emitter, it won't send anything to the client. If you [create a custom service event](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html#custom-events) named `testEvent` you will be able to do

```
app.service('myservice').emit('testEvent', 'this will be published to clients');
```

You can also emit any Socket.io event on `app.io` directly but it will not go through Feathers channel/publishing mechanism.